# Curl Error "HTTP error before end of send, stop sending" when sending SOAP request php

Tags: php, web-services, iis, curl, soap

So i need to interact with a SOAP API, im sending my soap message via curl with the following function

```
    /**
     * @param $soap_msg
     * @return int
     */
    function send($soap_msg)
    {

        //init curl
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set some debug
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        //set request method
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        //set some other options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);

        //set auth info
        $username = 'user';
        $password = '%PASS$';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);

        //build header array
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8';
        $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
       $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
        $headers[] = 'Expect: 100-continue';
        $headers[] = 'SOAPAction: http://ACTION/URL';
        $headers[] = "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_msg);

        //set headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        //set payload
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap_msg);

        //set soap resource
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://SOME.URL.co.uk/SERVICE.svc/detail');

        //execute request
        curl_exec($ch);

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $info;
    }

    echo send($soap_msg);
?>
```

passed SOAP message

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://my.action/endpoint/GetJob</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:b7747707-97cc-4edf-9cb0-b8dd40f45509</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://my.webservice.co.uk/Appt/AppointWS/service.svc/detail</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2015-09-08T19:52:16.065Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2015-09-08T19:57:16.065Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-2c7e3d75-b18d-480a-979e-57e6a042e9f2-2">
        <o:Username>user</o:Username>
        <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">%pass$</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetJob xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <jobEntryId>630422258</jobEntryId>
      <jobNo1>3874527</jobNo1>
      <contractId>220000</contractId>
    </GetJob>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The echo'd out put gives a 500 error

> < HTTP/1.1 100 Continue < Via: 1.1 FERNTMG01 < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal
>   Server Error < Connection: Keep-Alive < Content-Length: 648 < Date:
>   Wed, 09 Sep 2015 16:38:58 GMT < Content-Type: application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8
>   * Server Microsoft-IIS/7.5 is not blacklisted < Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 < X-Clacks-Overhead: GNU Terry Pratchett
>   * HTTP error before end of send, stop sending < 
>   * Closing connection 0 500

I stripped the basics of this function from one i wrote last week for a different SOAP service which worked fine so i'm a bit stumped as to what the problem is

edit:
Just tried this in an external client on mac 'Restinsoap' and i get back the following response still a 500

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
    <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:588e5592-c60a-4c2d-b643-c6af9c4772f5</a:RelatesTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <s:Code>
        <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
        <s:Subcode>
          <s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</s:Value>
        </s:Subcode>
      </s:Code>
      <s:Reason>
        <s:Text xml:lang="en-GB">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</s:Text>
      </s:Reason>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But if i execute in wcfstorm on a windows machine the request is fine

Answer (score 0):

SOAP services expect authentication details in header section of the payload.

Try adding this WSS Token in header section (`<x:Header>?</x:Header>`) of the payload in RestInSoap Client.

Change the username & password as required.

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
        <wsse:Username>asd</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">asd</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">8lrPhyvoNtE8Gp0wOJMcOw==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2015-09-10T05:17:40.296Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
```

Comment: yes i havent included the SOAP message that im sending but we send a fully formatted SOAP message with these details. As said i can send from a windows based SOAP client fine but when php im getting errors

Comment: i added the sent envelope in the original question